# store SimpleXMLElement Object value and images in database

Tags: php, xml, rss-reader

I'm trying to read a rss feed and store its value in my database . for this I'm using this

```
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://showmycode.co.in/supermob/feeds/rss/Jaipur');
    $movies = new SimpleXMLElement($homepage);
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($movies);
```

and then I found

```
     SimpleXMLElement Object
```

(
         [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.00
        )

```
[channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [title] => supermobdeal
        [description] => best discount accross canada        
        [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [lastBuildDate] => Thu, Nov 3rd 2011, 00:32 GMT 
        [generator] => supermobdeal
        [image] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [url] => http://showmycode.co.in/supermob/app/webroot/img/site_logo.png
                [title] => supermobdeal
                [link] => http://showmycode.co.in/supermob/app/webroot/img/site_logo.png
                [description] => Feed provided by supermobdeal
            )

        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => Let your 
                        [link] => http://showmycode.co.in/supermob/homes/index/Jaipur/25
                        [small_image_url] => http://showmycode.co.in/supermob/app/webroot/img/uploads/product_images/small/

                        [description] =>  trainers r any course



                        [start_date] => 2011-10-26
                        [end_date] => 2011-11-30
                        [start_time] => 09:26:00
                        [end_time] => 09:26:50
                        [price] => 50$
                        [value] => 199$
                        [discount] => 74.87%
                        [city] => Jaipur
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => Feel a
                        [link] => http://showmycode.co.in/supermob/homes/index/Jaipur/31
                        [small_image_url] => http://showmycode.co.in/supermob/app/webroot/img/uploads/product_images/small/3b8d0_Jaip_OrientSpa_24thOct_M_1.jpg

                        [description] => Orient Spa 
                        [city] => Jaipur
                    )

                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => Feel a
                        [link] => http://showmycode.co.in/supermob/homes/index/Jaipur/26
                        [small_image_url] => http://showmycode.co.in/supermob/app/webroot/img/uploads/product_images/small/0a646_Bombay-Biryani1.jpg

                        [description] => Taxes 



                        [city] => Jaipur
                    )

            )

    )
```

)
 how can I store tittle , link or other attributes in my database and store image in folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   //get contanints from SimpleXMLElement Object
    foreach($movies->channel->item as $opt){
    $title= $opt->title;
    $tittle=mysql_real_escape_string($title); //for Escapes special characters in a    string you can use for all varriables if require
     $link=$opt->link;
     $des=$opt->description;
     $image=$opt->medium_image_url;

    //for store image from http url to my folder
    $ch = curl_init($image);
    $fp = fopen('images/'. time () .'.'.'jpg', 'wb');//path for store image 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);

    include('db.php');//config file for db connection
     $sql="INSERT INTO rss (tittle, link, image,description,city)
     VALUES ('$tittle', '$link', '$image','$des','$city')";//insert record in database table
        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die('Error, insert query failed');
```

this code store varriables value in your database and image in folder from http url.thanks..